# Pull only one file from collaborators repository on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I'm really new to GitHub so please excuse my super layman terminology.

User A has added me to his project as a collaborator. I'm user B and I have a copy of his project. Now, I've locally made some changes to one file and pushed it to my own Github account. I want to know how user B can now pull only that one file (and not all changed files) into his own repository.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From scratch, you would do the following: first fork their repo. Then clone down your fork

```
git clone url_to_your_fork.git
```

Make a new branch that you want to make changes on

```
git checkout -b some/branch/name
```

Then you can make your changes. To just deliver a single file

```
git add some_file_name
```

Then `commit` it

```
git commit -m "your commit message"
```

Then `push` it

```
git push --set-upstream origin some/branch/name
```

Then you can do a "pull request" from your branch to that other user's repository.

The key to only delivering the one changed file is during `git add`. If you `git add *` or `git add -u` it will stage *all* modified files instead of a specific one.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer CoryKramer, is it also possible that when the other user does a pull request he can specify only 1 file to pull and not get all files which are changed?

Comment: No you cannot. You can only pull an entire commit. A commit is a set of changes, so you can't pull specific files out of the commit.

Comment: @Sophia111: no. Git deals in *commits*, not files. Every commit contains a full snapshot of all files, and every Git-to-Git transfer operations copies a whole number of commits. But suppose you obtain new commit *X*, and *X* itself changes only one file with respect to whatever came before *X*. You can then *merge* the whole set of changes associated with commit *X* ... and that *whole set of all files* is just one file. That's what the committing instructions above do: they make one whole new commit where the whole commit differs by just the one file.

Comment: Got it, thanks guy, I guess it makes sense to then just add only the required file during git add, that should give the desired outcome!